# Jolt Identify Transform and copying fields gives array instead of valie

Tags: jolt

I have the following json input:

```
{
  "incoming": {
    "data": {
      "attributes": {
        "displayName": "TestDisplayName1",
        "authors": "TestAuthors1",
        "summary": "TestSummary1"
      }
    }
  },
  "overriddenValues": {
    "data": {
      "attributes": {
        "displayName": "TestDisplayName2",
        "authors": "TestAuthors2",
        "summary": "TestSummary3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I expect the following output:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "displayName" : "TestDisplayName2",
      "authors" : "TestAuthors1",
      "summary" : "TestSummary1"
    }
  }
}
```

With the following Jolt spec(Identity transform):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "incoming": {
        "@": ""
      },
      "overriddenValues": {
        "data": {
          "attributes": {
            "displayName": "data.attributes.displayName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I get the following output:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "attributes" : {
      "displayName" : [ "TestDisplayName1", "TestDisplayName2" ],
      "authors" : "TestAuthors1",
      "summary" : "TestSummary1"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea why the output for **displayName** has an array of values when it should have been a single value.

Tried the following workaround:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "incoming": {
        "@": ""
      },
      "overriddenValues": {
        "data": {
          "attributes": {
            "displayName": "data.attributes.displayName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "attributes": {
          "*": "data.attributes.&",
          "displayName": {
            "1": "data.attributes.displayName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but it has it obvious pitfall, if the **displayName** field is not present in incoming.data.attributes, **displayName** will be missing in the output.

Any lead would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: "displayName" become an array because you write to the same key twice and values are collected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out a way to get the transformation. This spec gives the expected output:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "incoming": {
        "data": {
          "attributes": {
            "displayName": null,
            "*": "data.attributes.&"
          }
        }
      },
      "overriddenValues": {
        "data": {
          "attributes": {
            "displayName": "data.attributes.displayName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```